# Why do I get this error from HTC Sync when synchronising Outlook 2007 with my HTC Desire?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, android

When I synchronise my Outlook 2007 contacts and calendar with my (brand new) HTC Desire Android handset my contacts synchronise just fine but I get an error when synchronising the calendar.

The error reported by the HTC Sync application on the PC is:

`The Expression Service failed to start and might not be installed. To help resolve this problem, on the Help menu, click Office Diagnostics, or run Microsoft Office Setup again.`

I can't actually find the Office Diagnostics mentioned and my last phone (a Palm Treo 750v running Windows Mobile 6) sync'd just fine.

The HTC Desire is running Android 2.1-update1.
The version of HTC Sync installed on the PC is 2.0.33.
The PC is running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: You should try installing the latest version of HTC Sync. That's what solved [my problem](http://superuser.com/questions/599815/why-do-i-get-the-error-no-outlook-profiles-were-found-in-htc-sync/599865#599865). I liked the old versions better, but since it no longer works I have to use the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking my question the Android Stack Exchange site went live. I asked this question:

> [Is there a better sync application for Windows than HTCSync?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204/is-there-a-better-sync-application-for-windows-than-htcsync)