# Why do I get the error "no Outlook profiles were found" in HTC Sync?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have encountered a problem with HTC Sync. I have version 2.0.28. I had one of the latest versions of HTC Sync before I installed this. I didn't like it because it seemed to lag a little bit and overall it was just like a [bloatware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bloat) with a lot of makeup. I uninstalled it and then I installed this version which came with my phone.

Installation was successful. At first the phone didn't find the HTC Sync on the computer, but I think this was resolved after rebooted the computer. So the phone now finds HTC Sync.

But now when I go to Sync Manager, Tools, Settings, Contacts, select `MS Outlook 2000/2002/2003/2007 - Contacts` and click Properties button, I get the following error message.

> No Outlook profiles were found. Please ensure that at least one
>   Outlook profile exists.

I get the same message if I go to Sync Manager, Tools, Settings, Calendar.

It can't find the Outlook profile. Why not? Is there a way I can specify where my Outlook profile is? Is there a registry entry I can edit maybe?

[image: sync manager settings]

[image: sync manager]

If I try to synchronize anyway, this is what I get if I initiate the sync from the phone.

[image: sync summary]

It says 2 general errors and 1 calendar error found, due to synchronization not being able to start. It synchronized 0 of 1 item total. I wonder what that 1 item is.

Comment: I tried uninstalling it, then cleaning the registry (applications, application paths, installer, obsolete software, MUI cache) with CCleaner. I then installed it again. The problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the latest version of HTC Sync (3.3.53). Syncing contacts and calenders with Outlook works now again. The install took well over 20 minutes! Besides HTC Sync the setup also installed Adobe AIR (3.7.0) and HTC Driver Installer (4.1.0). This added even more time to the lengthy installation process. The setup removed previous version of HTC Sync. This probably added even more time to the total installation time.

This version also has the option to allow me to choose the Outlook profile/folder. Unfortunately you can't even access the options unless you connect a compatible phone and the phone is recognized. There are absolutely zero options unless you connect the phone!! This is rather ridiculous!

[image: htc install]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]